# Flask app doesn´t answer to the public IP in a Windows EC2 instance

Tags: windows, ubuntu, flask, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to publish a Flask app in a Windows EC2 instance. When I run:

> flask run --port 80 --host=0.0.0.0

It shows:

> Running on http://<private_IP>/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

If I try to access http://<private_IP>/ or http://<public_IP>/ from my local machine it doesn´t works.

I know that I'm ok with port permissions because if I run IIS and access  http://<public_IP> it works, so I suppose that Flask decides to answer only <private_ip> requisitions.

Am I sure? How can I fix that?

**Note**: I tried the same in a Ubuntu EC2 instance and the problem remains exactly the same.

Answer (score -1):

run it using a debug mode --debug that will show you wich addresses/ports are used for listening to requests.

Comment: If I run flask run --port 80 --host=0.0.0.0 --debugger (there's no --debug option) the only information about IP is the same:  "Running on http://<local_ip>:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)".

Comment: If I try to access it from outside no additional information is shown.

Comment: can you check a telnet from your local machine on port 80. maybe you need to check the windows firewall as well.

Comment: As I explained above, there's no problem with the firewall or AWS security because IIS is answering my local machine when active on the server.

Comment: I created a new Linux Ubuntu EC2 instance and installed my flask app and the problem is the same: Flask shows the message: "Running on <internal_ip> and I can´t access the app.

Comment: I changed to nginx and it's working now.